# HTML DOM rendering is getting blocked in iPhone (iOS 13) device

Tags: javascript, html, ios, dom, html5-audio

I am creating a URL stream music player in web with JavaScript. Everything is working fine in android device. While in iPhone devices DOM rendering is getting blocked. I have adjusted all JS position in HTML file but still it is not working. For demo please check [here](http://ebulawaa.com/sourabh/onemusic)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by setting src value by Javascript. Earlier I have provided a default stream URL in HTML file which causes this issue.